# Python Overall evaluation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of lists (listA) and I have another separate list (listB). I am trying to check if the listB matches any of the lists inside listA based on type and position which I have done in the testing12 function. My question is what can I do that would make the if statement give me an overall evaluation i.e true or false. True for when there is one or more match and False if there are no matches at all.

```
listA = [[3,"alpha"], [7, 8], ["hat", "bat"]]

listB = [5,5]


def testing12(x,y):
    result = map(type, x) == map(type, y)
    return result


for n in lists:
    if testing12(list,n) == True:
       print "True"
    else:
       print "False"
```

Comment: [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any)

Comment: What is `list` in `testing12(list, n)`? If it's the builtin `list`, `map(type, list)` will throw an error.

Comment: sorry list in testin12(list, n) is meant to be listB

Answer (score 5):

You want to use the [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) or [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) built-ins:

```
if any(testing12(list, n) for n in lists):
    print("at least one matched")
```

Or:

```
if all(testing12(list, n) for n in lists):
    print("All lists matched")
```